# How to fix "error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist" when compiling using command line in Intellij (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line-arguments

I have been trying to compile my Java code using the format `javac Main.java` but for some reason the compiler says that my package does not exist and as a matter of fact it is in the project structure, here is a screenshot:

[image: Files structure of my code]

The exact error is: `Main.java:1: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`

And my code looks like this in my Main.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;


public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: Main [file path]");
            return;
        }

        UdacisearchClient client =
                new UdacisearchClient(
                        "CatFacts LLC",
                        17,
                        8000,
                        5,
                        Instant.now(),
                        Duration.ofDays(180),
                        ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"),
                        "555 Meowmers Ln, Riverside, CA 92501");

        Path outputPath = Path.of(args[0]);
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.writeValue(Files.newBufferedWriter(outputPath), client);

        System.out.println("Wrote to: "+ outputPath.toAbsolutePath());
        UdacisearchClient deserialized = objectMapper.
                readValue(Files.newBufferedReader(outputPath), UdacisearchClient.class);

        System.out.println("Deserialized: " + deserialized);

    }
}
```

The whole code is supposed to compile like this `javac Main.java` and then `java Main client.json`. When I try to compile it by going to `Run`, `Edit Configurations` and by adding `client.json` as the argument of my program it works like a charm, my object is serialized as a json object in the `client.json` file  but when I compile using command line it says no package is found. The same error happens for any other dependency I try to use. It should be noted that when I instantiate objects from my dependency it looks fine as the `import` lines related to those objects aren't red. So I guess my issue resides in my command line compilation or my Intellij environment. I have tried many of the solution proposed online but the problem remains. I would like some help please.

Comment: Did you add the jackson dependency in your  POM.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: @BlaineWilsey I don't use a pom.xml or a build.gradle. I just added the libraries doing `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Librairies` -> `New Project Library` and selecting my libraries from my `lib` folder

Comment: @user16320675 I said `com.packagename,package` because I have the same issue for whatever dependency I try to use, I just wanted to be generic. `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` is my package indeed.

Comment: @BlaineWilsey _I don't use a pom.xml or a build.gradle. I just added the libraries doing File -> Project Structure -> Librairies -> New Project Library and selecting my libraries from my lib folder_


-> Your libraries need to be the part of build.  When you run your class from command line, you are probably not creating and executing the jar and therefore it doesn't know about your libraries.  Either use maven/gradle for dependencies and then use it to build the project (jar) or lookup how to create and execute jar: https://www.baeldung.com/java-run-jar-with-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was simple.

First compiling the libraries inside the **lib** folder and **Main.java** doing :

`javac -cp ".;lib/*" Main.java`

Then running my class **Main** (containing my **main** function):

`java -cp ".;lib/*" Main`

I was missing on the dot "**.**" and the semicolon **;**!